# How do I use Single Sign On with Kerio Winroute Firewall?

Tags: firewall

How do I use Single Sign on with Kerio Winroute Firewall?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched over from Winroute Firewall to Cyberoam UTM as KWF has absolutely NO support for single sign on.

As of today,the version they have has a feature called NTLM   (browser authentication) which cannot be centrally managed through Active Directory. You cannot set policies for firefox from the server.

So,In my opinion atleast,there is no single sign on feature in KWF.They claim NTLM to be SSO tho.

Incase anyone is planning to buy kwf,check this feature.

Thanks for the time...

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:
[Kerio WinRoute Firewall Active Directory domains mapping](http://www.kerio.com/manual/kwf/en/sect-domains.html)